# How can I discard any injected scripts from the absolute path of a page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xss

I'm trying to get the absolute path of a uri in a MVC ASP.NET webpage.
I'm using the

```
Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

But this can be hacked using some clever XSS technique by giving a url like

```
http://example.com/about/%27%3bfunc(document.cookie)%3b%27gfg
```

This would give me the "absolute url"

```
/about/';func(document.cookie);'
```

by using the Request object above. So how can this be avoided?

Cheers
Jens

Comment: First, no repro. Calling `new Uri("http://example.com/about/%27%3bfunc(document.cookie)%3b%27gfg").AbsolutePath` returns `/about/%27%3bfunc(document.cookie)%3b%27gfg` as expected. Are you using an old .NET version perhaps? There were some changes in 4.5. The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2

Comment: Second, there are no invalid characters in this string. What do you mean "hacked" and XSS? This won't get executed *unless* the view code used the raw text to generate a link instead of using eg a relative path or a URL helper. Please post the affected view code

Comment: We're using .NET 4.0. I may have put the question wrong. The goal is to get a 'clean' absolute url without query parameters and obvious attemps to inject xss code on the webpage.

Comment: We have this google tag manager script, that want's to output the url in a script block hidden in the markup.

Comment: The answer is the same - just don't use the raw path. The problem is that what you posted *is* the actual URL of your page, it's not something that was injected: the browser asked for a page with that URL, and your server responded on that URL. Therefore, to any client that is the page's URL.

Comment: Your code could redirect the request or just refuse it - why would an `about` page accept anything? Or use [UrlHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx) instead of AbsolutePath to return the path to a specific action or route. `Url.Action()` should return the current page's route

Comment: You should definitely replace `AbsolutePath` with `Url.Action()` in such cases, but you should probably check *why* this route was allowed. Your routing configuration probably needs to be stricter

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments. I've decided to go with a dead simple string.Replace and take out %() from the url. This would avoid any xss attempts.

Comment: It won't. It may fix *this* problem. Why don't you ensure the URL is correct in the first place? Why allow a bad URL? It's the *web application itself* that decided to accept the bad URL

Comment: So, if someone decides to create a page with URLs to your site with "interesting" suffixes like `Admin` or `admin.php`, these will still end up in Google analytics and indexes, available to script kiddies that look for just such URLs to attack.